# Firebase Function writes wrong key to firebase database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function and i call it directly in app.

my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sharePost = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  var postkey = data.text;
  const uid = data.uid;

  var list= [];

  var db = admin.database();

var ref = db.ref("users").child(uid).child("followers");
  ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    list.push(childKey);
  });
  var refsave = db.ref("posts");

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    refsave.child(list[i]).update({
      postkey:""
    });
  }

});

});
```

And i call this function with this code:

```
private Task<String> sharePost(String text) {
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("text", text);
        data.put("uid",auth.getUid());

        return mFunctions
                .getHttpsCallable("sharePost")
                .call(data)
                .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                        String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
                        return result;
                    }
                });
    }
```

I put post key(something like this : -LUpD2kWvUct5KiihU4M) in this task and what i wanna do is writing that key.but instead of that function write data under variable name.

This image tells better what i want

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to update multiple values you can create update object and write them all at once.

Also update is different then `set()`. Update object key is the path to update and value will be written at that path. Also the path is relative to the child on which you will call `update()`.

Update your firebase functions like this:

```
var ref = db.ref("users").child(uid).child("followers");
ref.once('value', function (snapshot) {
    let update={};
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        update[`${childKey}/${postkey}`]="THE VALUE YOU WILL STORE"
    });
    var refsave = db.ref("posts");

    return refsave.update(update);

});
```

For more details on how update works in admin sdk please see the documents. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#update

Comment: it deleted all child keys and set value to parent key

Comment: I have updated the answer, I forgot to add the postkey in update.